# Lagg failover FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd

I've tried using channel bonding(active-backup) in ubuntu and it worked well . I could understand that the bonded interfaces are monitored by MII monitoring and when an interface goes down and slave takesover it sends a gratuitous arp for updating neighbour cache . I tried to achieve the same in FreeBSD by using the lagg interface. However I could'nt understand how the link states are monitored . lagg also does not send any gratuitous arp. So how does lagg (active failover ) work ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the section in the FreeBSD handbook that talks about Link Aggregation and failover?

https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-aggregation.html

Make sure you load the if_lagg kernel module in /boot/loader.conf:

```
if_lagg_load="YES"
```

The, in rc.conf, bring your ethernet devices up and create a lagg0 interface with those as members:

```
ifconfig_igb0="UP polling"
ifconfig_igb1="UP polling"
ifconfig_igb2="UP polling"
ifconfig_igb3="UP polling"
ifconfig_lagg0="create laggproto lacp laggport igb0 laggport igb1 laggport igb2 laggport igb3 128.115.132.165 netmask 255.255.255.0"
```

I wrote a blog post about it a few years ago, it is still fairly accurate:
https://mywushublog.com/2010/04/lagg-freebsd/

You will need to configure your switch ports for LACP

Comment: Thank you for your answer . I am not using lacp here (which uses lacpdu). What I'm concerned is how laggproto failover  works without lacpdu and all those stuff. And also I can understand how to configure it but not how it works

Comment: I see now. I have only use the lacp option for laggproto, and not fail over (I tend to use two separate systems with CARP)

For a more detailed explanation of how the failover protocol works, you might want to take a look at the code:

https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/sys/net/if_lagg.c?view=markup

It looks like lagg_fail_input checks the interface if it returns a null value or not.

That is as far as I can go with it :) Hope you find what you are looking for!